# Cache object in model for multiple operation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2. I have the following code:

```
# photo.rb
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :associate_current_user

  private

  def associate_current_user
    current_user = UserSession.find.user
    self.user_id = current_user.id
  end
end
```

Before a new record is created, it searches for the `current_user`. This is alright if it's just 1 new record at a time. But if there are 100 records to be created, it's gonna search for the same `current_user` 100 times. There is definitely performance issue.

Is there a way I can cache the object for similar operation, or any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code that creates multiple photos? If it's in a controller, you're better off loading the user there, once, and passing it to each of the create statements. Loading a user from the session in the model is sort of a violation of the MVC paradigm.

Comment: For some reasons, I'm not using the controller to create the photo. I'm using this method: http://www.tkalin.com/blog_posts/multiple-file-upload-with-rails-3-2-paperclip-html5-and-no-javascript My Photo Controller is totally empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do memoization, something as follow

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend ActiveSupport::Memoizable
  after_create :associate_current_user

  private

  def associate_current_user
    current_user = UserSession.find.user
    self.user_id = current_user.id
  end
  associate_current_user
end
```

Comment: Can I remove `self.user_id = current_user.id` and cache the `associate_current_user`, then call this within the same model just to prevent it from searching for the user object again? What happens if multiple users are uploading photos? When will the cached object be removed? Thanks.